# TCA9548a + TCS34725 + Arduino MEGA not identifying the sensors

Tags: arduino, adafruit

I'm trying to use the arduino mega with a TCA9548A multiplexer and two color sensors, but I'm not able to connect the arduino with the two sensors.
When I try to scan the TCA9548A it returns that there are no I2Cs connected.

```
/**
   TCA9548 I2CScanner.pde -- I2C bus scanner for Arduino
   Based on code c. 2009, Tod E. Kurt, http://todbot.com/blog/
*/

#include "Wire.h"

#define TCAADDR 0x70

void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}


// standard Arduino setup()
void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\nTCA9548A Scanner ready!");

  for (uint8_t t = 0; t < 8; t++) {
    tcaselect(t);
    Serial.print("TCA Port #"); Serial.println(t);

    for (uint8_t addr = 0; addr <= 127; addr++) {
      
      // Don't report on the TCA9548A itself!
      if (addr == TCAADDR) continue;

      // See whether a device is on this address
      Wire.beginTransmission(addr);

      // See if something acknowledged the transmission
      int response = Wire.endTransmission();
      if (response == 0) {
        Serial.print("Found I2C 0x");  Serial.println(addr, HEX);
      }
    }

    // Slow the loop scanner down a bit
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("\nScan completed.");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

I've tried in several different ways and I'm not able to use this TCA9548A.

[image]

These first logs are with the TCS34725 (color sensor) connected to the Arduino without the TCA9548A.
The second is with the TCA9548A connected to the Arduino and the color sensors connected to it.

My config:
[image]

### [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why the clock and data to MCU have funny names? Is the mux itself present on bus? Do you have schematics or manuals of modules you use and have you verified they should work together? Maybe you want to move this to Arduino.SE as you are simply using ready-made electrical products with Arduino?

Comment: Yes, there's even this tutorial where more than two color sensors are used with the TCA9548A https://www.hackster.io/sherwinchiu89/multiplexing-6-i2c-tcs34725-color-sensors-2a7272

Comment: Yes to which of my question? Have you got SDA and SCL the correct way around? It would help if you said the answers, like is the mux itself detected or not.

Comment: Could I test mux using an i2c scanner on Arduino?
I believe that the SDA and the SCL are correct, the SDA of the mux is connected to the SDA of the Arduino and the SCL to the SCL of the Arduino.And the sensors are also that way SDA to SDA, SCL to SCL.

Comment: Do you know whay your code does? It specifically skips testing the mux address.

Comment: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/tca9548a-i2c-multiplexer-esp32-esp8266-arduino/  When bus(x) is selected, it seems that Wire.beginTransmission or ...end... are no more used (?) Just initialize a "dummy" sensor and ask at address if it is (?).

Comment: Perhaps an answer here (scanner with generic multiplexer) https://github.com/akkoyun/I2C_Functions

Comment: Running the scanner above the result was this: https://ibb.co/3RVCNxB